# Sqlite query to convert string to date in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have date in string format in the table in yyyy-mm-dd format.
I want to convert that string to date format for further comparision on the date.

Any help would be greatful..

Comment: I am sorry guys. I forgot to mentions here. I want the query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the query of this.
SqlLite compares difference between two string date directly.

```
select column from Table where columnDate between '2012-07-01' and '2012-07-07'
```

But thanks for your interest guys.

Comment: This query work only because the date format is in standard ISO 8601, that preserve lexicographical order and chronological order. Is not different from `between 'AA' and 'ZZ' `. So it do not have anything common with Date type but only with Character.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use [SQLite - DateTime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) functions to compare field data value. Alternately you can use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class's `parse` method to convert string date to Date type.

Comment: Can you please tell me the query for this.